# Why static and global variables of class type are dangerous?

Tags: c++, c++11, global-variables

http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Static_and_Global_Variables

> Static or global variables of class type are forbidden: they cause
>   hard-to-find bugs due to indeterminate order of construction and
>   destruction.

If a global variable of class type doesn't lean on other global variables, such as `std::string strvar("abc")`, what's wrong/unsafe to use it?

The guide also said:

> ...in addition to banning globals of class type, we do not
>   allow static POD variables to be initialized with the result of a
>   function, unless that function (such as getenv(), or getpid()) does
>   not itself depend on any other globals.

I think `strvar` is fine for the same reason: its constructor doesn't itself depend on any other globals.

Also I wonder if C++11's looser definition of POD has any reflection in this regard?

Comment: The Google styling guide is not the catch-all guide for styling in C++ nor should it ever be.

Comment: Did you click on the arrow icon to the left of that? It explains, in detail, and includes "This rule completely disallows `vector` (use C arrays instead), or `string` (use `const char []`)."

Comment: Read this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html

Comment: @GregHewgill Of course. That's why I ask this question: why disallow?

Comment: The Google C++ style guide is junk ... see https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140503193653-3046051-why-google-style-guide-for-c-is-a-deal-breaker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is apparently trying to keep the rules simple. So while there may be some cases where it's pretty safe, describing those exceptions would have been difficult. And the benefits of allowing these exceptions is probably not great enough to warrant this extra complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with global and static instances of classes is that the order in which they are constructed / destroyed is implementation dependent. This means that if you have code that relies on them being around at a certain time you will most likely get an unwelcome surprise.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of many classes, especially the ones in the Google standard libraries, rely on global state that is initialized at the beginning of the program. Class constructors can open network connections or fetch singletons in ways that do not obviously refer to other globals.

In general, constructors should be free to assume that globals they declared have been initialized, and this breaks if they happen to be called statically on a linker-initialized object.

Comment: But "Doing work in constructors" says that constructors should NOT do things like open network connections.

Comment: @Barmar: Again, see Rapptz comment. Google has two areas of expertise: search engines and advertising. That doesn't make them experts on C++ style.